# what is the difference between using static html tags and echo them via php

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, echo

I have a big project and my result page is constant. So I need to one constant page with *changeable contents*. That's why I have to use dynamic tags `echo '<div>anything</div>';` instead of static tags `<div>anything</div>`.

this is my **structure**:

```
// resultpage.php

<html>

<head>
    <?php
           switch ($_GET['arg']) {
               case 'one':
                   $contents = '<div>content 1</div>';
                   break;
               case 'two':
                   $contents = '<div>content 2</div>';
                   break;
    ?>
</head>

<body>
   <?php echo $contents; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

**Point:** In reality `$contents` is included more than 200 lines.

Now I want to know, what happens for each request ?! In this model, my bandwidth will be waste ? Is it better to I create separated file for each content *(included static html tags)* ? something like this:

```
// content1.php

<html><head></head>
<body> <div>content 1</div> </body>
</html>

// content2.php

<html><head></head>
<body> <div>content 2</div> </body>
</html>

// And creating a php file contained switch() for selecting contents.
```

Anyway which method is more optimized ? In fact I want to know when one user give to my site a request, what happens into server for my html and php tags ?

It should be noted that my result page uses ajax and page will not get refresh. returning only plaintext data is better OR returning all contents *(contained html tags)* ? *(while the page is constant and not refresh)*

Comment: create a single html file and use php to manipulate results inside it. Why complicate it.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal look, my result page is using ajax and the page will not be refresh, in this case (as you said), my content every thim should `echo`. is it not bad ?

Comment: No it does not matter for the bandwidth of the server. Everything inside PHP is `interpreted` at the serverside. The client only receives the generated output, the correct `html` page in this case

Comment: @DarkBee ah I see, then there is not any difference. just tell me, If the contents of a page be `echo` every time while it can be constant in the page, also you say it does not matter ? look, I'm using ajax and my static tags can be constant in my page, Is It not bad to I `echo` every time all of them ?

Comment: If the mainparts of your site stays the same then I recommend only to update the containers of which the ajax is meant to update/get dynamic content for

Answer (score 1):

You asked about bandwidth usage: it is very likely that you won't notice the difference, since that is the amount of data that travels through the network. In each case, the amount of data is the same, but the difference is *how* you generate that data.

As for the static files, the PHP pre-processor does not need to be involved, which will grant you a slightly better performance, but at the cost of maintainability.

**For PHP: Advantages**

As other answers had already pointed out, it is very recommendable that you take the PHP approach with the dynamic contents of the pages. This will save you from having multiple copies that you need to maintain each time that you want to perform a change in all of the pages (for example, adding classes for styling).

Well done, PHP can save you a lot of effort into minimizing the amount of code that you have duplicated.

Finally, there are things you just can't do with static files, and you need to resort to any kind of preprocessor. PHP is one of the most popular ones and any hosting company is likely to support it.

**Against PHP: Disadvantages**

On the downside, there's the configuration of the server itself. Any HTTP server can host static files, but you need to have PHP available in order to preprocess PHP files.

Also, a little pre-processing will have to be done each time that the pages are served. This is likely not a problem if there's not many computations that you need to do, but this is CPU time.

Finally, there's the support of the PHP server itself. Using PHP incorrectly can open you up to security issues, and the server needs to be kept up to date and patched so that it is secure. If you were to avoid PHP altogether, this wouldn't be a worry (at least not for PHP).

Comment: then what is your offer ? echo them or using static html tags ?

Comment: @stack It really depends on your scenario, but if I were you, yes, I'd go with PHP and reusing code. If you have lots of pages, it could become a maintainability nightmare.

Comment: you know what is my problem ?! that is using ajax, look, when I send a request, is it better to it gives me just plaintext contents or it gives me all contents (contained html tags) ?? (while the page is constant and not refresh)

Comment: @stack AJAX are HTTP requests like any other, so all my points above still hold. I'd choose for the AJAX response to be as small as possible, since those are going to affect the user experience, and will be easier to process and display on the screen. Load as much as you can on the original page, and use the AJAX requests for the small bits that you need later.

Answer (score 0):

You should base your pages off of the template/structure of your HTML. If the HTML is consistent, aside from the content then you should be using the same page and just use PHP to determine what the content is. Ideally, this content should be pulled from a database with a separate interface to manipulate/edit the content (CMS).

If the structure/layout of the page is so totally different that your current template can't accommodate, then you should create a new template, with a new structure.

Ideally, you should split recurring items into seperate files (ie header, footer, sidebar, etc). Then you can easily call those sections into your templates, and easily update those sections across all of your pages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes my content is so totally different, then ? what is your mean of *'then you should create a new template, with a new structure.'* ? your mean is I `echo` them ?

Comment: Imagine the HTML is the framework of the house and the content is the color of the house. The color means absolutely nothing to how the structure is actually laid out. Therefore you should be looking at the framework, and using the same framework (php page) for all pages that it can apply to. If the structure of the page (minus the content) is totally different that it can't be manipulated with PHP then you should use a new template (php page).

Comment: and finally, you know what is my problem ?! that is using ajax, look, when I send a request, is it better to it gives me just plaintext contents or it gives me all contents (contained html tags) ?? (while the page is constant and not refresh)

Comment: I'd send the content already formatted in HTML (p tags, etc), Then just put it in your "content container"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its true that you can do the same thing using static html. Is it dynamic? To answer this question PHP will be voted over html. Because if you have variable number of content. Suppose, do don't know content you have, then you should use PHP, then you can show all of your content using some programming condition and loop. But it is true that the situation for the particular system you are talking about html is ok to handle your requirement because here there is some static switch case, can are just displaying some particular number of content. Though if you intend to change your content you have to change your code, but if you use php you can just change the content column of your db then the content of your site will be changed.